# iptables block but then allow to same destination

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables

I have a RaspberryPi on my LAN with default policies of DENY for in/out/forward. I want to open outgoing to four IP-addresses and allow responses to come back, but not accept new connections from outside.

I don't understand why most outgoing connections are blocked while some are allowed a couple of seconds later. See this from the log:

```
[Sat Nov 24 15:37:56 2018] IPTABLES:DROP: IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.0.40 DST=104.24.15.89 LEN=176 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=3938 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=36512 DPT=80 WINDOW=115 RES=0x00 ACK PSH FIN URGP=0 
[Sat Nov 24 15:38:03 2018] IPTABLES:ACCEPT:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.0.40 DST=104.24.15.89 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=34819 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=36708 DPT=80 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
[Sat Nov 24 15:38:03 2018] IPTABLES:ACCEPT:IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=b8:27:eb:c2:4a:fc:a4:2b:8c:96:76:e5:08:00:45:00:00:30:00:00:40:00:38:06:c1:2f SRC=104.24.15.89 DST=10.0.0.40 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=36708 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0 
[Sat Nov 24 15:38:03 2018] IPTABLES:DROP: IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.0.40 DST=104.24.15.89 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=34820 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=36708 DPT=80 WINDOW=115 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
[Sat Nov 24 15:38:03 2018] IPTABLES:DROP: IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.0.40 DST=104.24.15.89 LEN=176 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=34821 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=36708 DPT=80 WINDOW=115 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
```

This is how I created the rules:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT 4 -d 104.24.14.89 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j LOG_ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT 5 -d 104.24.15.89 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j LOG_ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT 6 -d 107.170.105.41 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j LOG_ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT 7 -d 64.30.224.206 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j LOG_ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 4 -s 104.24.14.89 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j LOG_ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 5 -s 104.24.15.89 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j LOG_ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 6 -s 107.170.105.41 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j LOG_ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 7 -s 64.30.224.206 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j LOG_ACCEPT
```

These are all the rules:

```
root@notremusique(rw):~# iptables -L --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     all  --  10.0.0.0/24          anywhere            
2    ACCEPT     all  --  localhost            anywhere            
3    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:ntp
4    LOG_ACCEPT  all  --  104.24.14.89         anywhere             ctstate ESTABLISHED
5    LOG_ACCEPT  all  --  104.24.15.89         anywhere             ctstate ESTABLISHED
6    LOG_ACCEPT  all  --  107.170.105.41       anywhere             ctstate ESTABLISHED
7    LOG_ACCEPT  all  --  lastfm-api-vip1.phx1.cbsig.net  anywhere             ctstate ESTABLISHED
8    LOG_DROP   all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.0.0.0/24         
2    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             localhost           
3    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ntp
4    LOG_ACCEPT  all  --  anywhere             104.24.14.89         ctstate NEW
5    LOG_ACCEPT  all  --  anywhere             104.24.15.89         ctstate NEW
6    LOG_ACCEPT  all  --  anywhere             107.170.105.41       ctstate NEW
7    LOG_ACCEPT  all  --  anywhere             lastfm-api-vip1.phx1.cbsig.net  ctstate NEW
8    LOG_ACCEPT  all  --  anywhere             134.25.4.0/24       
9    LOG_DROP   all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain LOG_ACCEPT (9 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level info prefix "IPTABLES:ACCEPT:"
2    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain LOG_DROP (2 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level info prefix "IPTABLES:DROP: "
2    DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
root@notremusique(rw):~#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `OUTPUT`, you allow cstate `NEW`,but not `ESTABLISHED`.

As a consequence, the initial packet of a connection will get through, but all other packets will be dropped.